# Trapping F1 with ProcessCmdKey calls two web pages

Tags: vb.net

I am using ProcessCmdKey to catch the F1 key in order to then show appropriate help screens from the web in the browser. It all works as expected except that the browser shows two web pages, mine and a Microsoft "How can we help you?" page.

The key factor is that my code is a COM Add-in for Outlook. It launches a form and the code contains this code:

```
Protected Overrides Function ProcessCmdKey(ByRef msg As System.Windows.Forms.Message, ByVal keyData As System.Windows.Forms.Keys) As Boolean
                Select Case keyData
                    Case Keys.F1
                        ShowHelp()
                        Return True
                    Case Else
                        Return MyBase.ProcessCmdKey(msg, keyData)
                End Select

                Return True
        End Function
```

It seems to me that my ShowHelp routine is called correctly but that Windows goes on to handle the F1 key itself by showing a page related to Office365. This happens whether I return True or False.

What am I missing?

Comment: Does it only show the two pages if you run it from VS - i.e., does it work as intended if you run the .exe? If not, the code of the `ShowHelp()` method might be useful.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for the reply Andy. If I comment out my ShowHelp sub then I still get the Microsoft web page though I don't get mine. Yes, I still get the MS web page if running the add-in from the DLL - not in VS. An Outlook expert of the Microsoft Outlook Developers forum said that Outlook would not pick up an external ProcessCmdKey instruction and that the only way to do it was trapping a lower-level Windows message. I have gone for the simpler option of adding a Help button to my form. – Mike VE